# Fancybox not repositioning correct after orientation change on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, fancybox, orientation

When rotating my iPad from portrait to landscape and back to portrait, the fancybox image gets a mysterious padding on the left. Plus, before changing rotations, I cannot scroll left or right, afterwards I can scroll to the left. Please refer to the images (observe the background!) for a better understanding.

[image: This is the screen before changing rotations]
[image: This is the screen after changing rotations]
[image: This is the screen after scrolling to the left]

What I already tried is to add the repositioning method of fancybox:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function(event) {
  $.fancybox.reposition();
});
```

Anyone has experienced this before or can guess where it might come from?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you solved this problem? currently struggling with exactly the same thing

Answer (score 5):

After attempting many things using jQuery mobile and calling various functions in Fancy Box, I figured out a very simple fix.

I've simply added the following parameter to my fancybox initializer :

```
autoCenter  : true
```

You can find the documentation on this setting here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Cannot guarantee that this will fix it for you but I hope so!

PS: This probably requires at least the 2.1.5 version of Fancy Box.

Comment: Man, you saved a lot of my time. Thank you!